# proving an isomorphism of two open sets (Hartshorne Corollary I 4.5)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be birational varieties and $\phi: X \rightarrow Y, \psi: Y \rightarrow X$ mutually inverse rational dominant maps. Let $\phi$ be represented by $(U,\phi_U)$ and $\psi$ by $(V,\psi_V)$. Then Hartshorne in Corollary I 4.5 says that the open sets $\phi_U^{-1}(\psi_V^{-1}(U)) \subset U$ and $\psi_V^{-1}(\phi_U^{-1}(V)) \subset V$ are isomorphic via $\phi$ and $\psi$ respectively.

I am wondering if he means that they are isomorphic as topological spaces or as varieties. Moreover, how can we actually see this isomorphism? It seems to me a little bit confusing. Here is the closest i got: $\phi_U(\phi_U^{-1}(\psi_V^{-1}(U)) \subset \psi_V^{-1}(U) = \psi_V^{-1}(\phi_U^{-1}(Y)) = \psi_V^{-1}(\phi_U^{-1}(V))^c$, where $^c$ denotes closure.

Answer (score 2):

He means isomorphic as varieties.  But there is surely a hypothesis missing in your statement: you have to assume that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are mutually inverse rational maps, and you will have to use this in proving the isomorphism.

Comment: @Matt E Sorry for bugging you like this, but have you seen this question <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463321/primes-of-ramification-index-1-with-inseparable-residue-field-extension>? I think everyone involved would love to hear your answer!