# Ramification and algebraic closure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-curves, ramification

Let $k$ be a field and $f:C\rightarrow B$ a morphism of smooth curves. Let $C'$, $B'$ and $f'$ be the extensions of $C$, $B$, and $f$ to $\overline{k}$.

Let $c\in C$, $b=f(c)$, $c'\in C'$ above $c$ and $b'=f'(c')$.

Is it true that the ramification index $e(c/b)$ is the same as the ramification index $e(c'/b')$?

Comment: It is true if $e(c/b)$ or $e(c'/b')$ is equal to $1$, because then it's unramifiedness we're talking about, and it is detected by $\Omega^1$ which behaves nicely with base change.  In general, I think it remains true if $k$ is perfect, because then the $C_{\overline{k}}\rightarrow C$ (same for $B$) correspond to unramified maps of valuation rings, thus $e(c/b)$ and $e(c'/b')$ are both the ramification indices of $\mathcal{O}_{B,b} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C',c'}$ (using either $\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$ or $\mathcal{O}_{B',b'}$ as intermediate rings). But I don't know for sure if $k$ isn't perfect.

Comment: In other words, we can assume that $k$ is separably closed, ie that $\overline{k}/k$ is purely inseparable. But then this base change is a universal homeomorphism, and then stranger things may happen. For instance, if $c$ is the only point of ramification above $b$, then the residual field extensions must all get smaller as we extend the base field (but the degree and fiber and ramifiedness remain the same), so the ramification index is forced to go up, unless $b$ and $c$ already had the same residue fields.

Comment: @Mindlack: thank you for your answer. This is now clear for me! You can put your comment as an answer, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the author, I'm turning my comment into an answer.

It is true if $e(c/b)$ or $e(c′/b′)$ is equal to 1 *and $k$ is perfect* (thank you @Daniel Hast for detecting this), because then it's unramifiedness we're talking about, and it is detected by whether $\Omega^1$ vanishes. But $\Omega^1$ behaves nicely with base change (and it's a faithfully flat base change).

In general, I think it remains true if $k$ is perfect, because then the $C_{\overline{k}} \rightarrow C$ (same for $B$) correspond to unramified maps of valuation rings, thus $e(c/b)$ and $e(c′/b′)$ are both the ramification indices of $\mathcal{O}_{B,b}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{C′,c′}$ (using either $\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$ or $\mathcal{O}_{B′,b′}$ as intermediate rings).

So what I showed is that we can assume that $\overline{k}/k$ is purely inseparable. But then, this base change is a universal homeomorphism, and stranger things may happen (as shown in the answer linked by Daniel Hast again).

Comment: "It is true if $e(c/b)$ or $e(c'/b')$ is equal to $1$"
This is incorrect; you also need the corresponding extension of residue fields to be separable. Here is an example showing that a point with ramification index 1 and inseparable residue field extension can have the ramification index increase upon base change to the algebraic closure: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/463936/41415
As explained in that answer, this is why the definition of "unramified" is "ramification index 1 *and separable residue field extension*".

Comment: Oops, that's a very good point. It would have been slightly easier to understand if you had quoted the rest of the sentence instead, which contains the reason why the argument doesn't work (that is, $\Omega^1$ vanishing requiring the condition on maximal ideals *and* separability of the field extension). So perhaps my last point is also incorrect.